# Converting colored segment of image to white

Tags: python, opencv, scikit-image

I am trying to use python OpenCV to convert Bill's segmented image to white color but have been unsuccessful in doing so. I would essentially like create a white silhouette of Bill in a black background.
I have stored the image in a variable called:

```
bill
```

Any solutions or direction will be highly appreciated. Thank you

[image: Segmented image of a Bill]

[image: silhouette bill]

This is the silhouette version of bill when applying the code suggested by frab:

```
graybill = cv2.cvtColor(bill, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
graybill[bill > 0] = 255
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is:

1. Convert image to grayscale

   `graybill = cv2.cvtColor(bill, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)`
2. Set all values of matrix equal to 255 if the value is greater than 0 (black)

   `graybill[graybill > 0] = 255`

An alternative is to use `threshold` from cv2:

```
ret,thresh1 = cv.threshold(img,1,255,cv.THRESH_BINARY)
```

Comment: I tried doing that but i seem to get an image that has a yellow silhouette of bill with a dark blue background (will update the image in the question)

Comment: Are you plotting the image using matplotlib? That could be the colormap, use cv2.imshow().

Comment: The issue was using  'graybill = cv2.cvtColor(bill, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)' where the output gives a green colored bill as opposed to gray.

Comment: Please use cv2.imshow() or either set cmap='gray' as argument to plt.imshow

Comment: matplotlib by default uses color table to pseudocolor a grayscale image. So that is why your background is purple and your foreground is yellow. You should simply use c2.imshow()